# Error while assigning response to any array in angular?

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular-httpclient

The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

```
 res : any[];
  constructor(http: HttpClient) { 
    http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.res = response;
    });
```

Comment: why do u even bother set a type if its any[]?
it means nothing...

Comment: Btw, it's a pretty bad idea to use http stuff in the constructor. Do it in `ngOnInit` instead

Comment: It is giving error while assigning  this.res = response

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign object type response to array type,
so you can push response to array like
 this.res.push(response);

Comment: Errors are corrected.but i am not getting any output. if i am logging in console i get all the values. but when i am trying to display in list i am not getting the output values

Comment: @Mohammedzuhair : could you show how you read the list elements to display them?